# How can I call a function with some parameters specified in parent environment?

Tags: r, eval

Consider the following function defined in global environment:

```
test <- function(x,y) {
  x+y
}
```

Using `eval(quote(test(1)),list(y=2))` does not work.

```
> eval(quote(test(1)),list(y=2))
Error in test(1) : object 'y' not found
```

It is because the function would not find `y` in `list(y=2)`. Is there a simple way that I can modify the way I evaluate it so that `test(1)` works in an environment where `y` is defined?

Comment: Do you mean to remove `y` from your `test` definition? `test <- function(x)`?

Comment: Why have you indicated that `y` is a parameter to the function? How will you know which one to use if a value is passed as `y`?

Comment: The function definition is still `test <- function(x,y)` but the input allows `test(1)` where `y` is missing. The question is how can I still evaluate `test(1)` where `y` is given in calling environment?

Comment: Would you be ok defining a new function `testx <- function(x) test(x, y)`, then just call `testx(1)`?

Comment: @flodel - interesting. To clarify for future readers, if a function uses an object that is not specified as an input argument, R goes hunting in the calling (global?) environment for it? So you could indirectly pass the `y` argument by doing: `test <- function(x) x + y; y <- 10; test(1);`

Comment: I think it searches in the environment where the function was defined. Try `eval(quote((function(x)test(x, y))(1)), list(y=2))` or `local((function(x)test(x, y))(1), list(y=2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safest way would be to define a default value of `y` from the parent frame if not supplied.

```
test<-function(x,y=get("y", envir=parent.frame(1))) {
    x+y
}

y<-3
test(1)
# [1] 4
test(1, 10)
# [1] 11
```

but really this sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Agreed that it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval_with <- function(fn, ..., stuff = parent.frame()) {
  args <- list(...) 
  for (arg in setdiff(intersect(ls(stuff), names(formals(fn))), names(args)))
    args[[arg]] <- stuff[[arg]]
  do.call(fn, args)
}
```

### Examples

```
local({
  print(eval_with(test, 1, stuff = list(y = 3))) # 4
  y <- 2
  print(eval_with(test, 1)) # 3
  print(eval_with(test, 1, 5 )) # 6
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

In `test()` below, if `y` is missing from the argument list, the functions looks for it in the global environment, and if found calculates `x + y`, Otherwise, it accepts the given `y` argument and uses that in the calculation.

```
> y <- 5
> test <- function(x, y) {
      if(missing(y)) y <- get("y", .GlobalEnv)
      x + y
  }
> test(1)      ## 1 + 5
# [1] 6
> test(1, 3)   ## 1 + 3
# [1] 4
```